# Spring Boot with GraphQL - schema issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I am playing around with GraphQL and Spring Boot, but I am stuck on this issue for a while now.

First, here is my build.gradle:

```
...
compile 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.10.0'
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '5.2.4'
runtime 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.10.0'
...
```

I have an entity, lets say - Dog, a Repository, Service, Mutator and a Query for it. In /resources I have `dogs.graphqls` with the schema in there.

But for some reason, I cannot get the app to start. The error message reads: `No graphql schema files found on classpath with location pattern '**/*.graphqls'`. When i remove the dependency to `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter` it starts, but does not find the schema.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed out the kickstarter dependencies with these:

```
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-spring-boot-starter', version: '5.0.2'
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '5.2.4'
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphiql-spring-boot-starter', version: '3.0.3'
```

:|

Answer (score 1):

Include the following code in pom.xml:

```
<resources>
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
        <include>**/*.graphqls</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a GraphQL spring-boot project and I see 2 differences:

- my schemas are in `resources/graphql` - probably doesn't matter
- some other dependencies - I remember playing with those dependencies to fix similar problems to this

Have a look - https://github.com/xShadov/code-hellven/blob/master/core/api/pom.xml - try using similar dependencies (not sure how it translates to gradle):

```xml
<graphql.version>5.4.1</graphql.version>
<graphql-datetime-spring-boot-starter.version>1.4.0</graphql-datetime-spring-boot-starter.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${graphql.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${graphql.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>voyager-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${graphql.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
  <version>${graphql.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.zhokhov.graphql</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-datetime-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${graphql-datetime-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
</dependency>
```